# By Using JavaScript "Undefined" (Variable) we can Free system memory?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing

I am working for an internet speed test application.  The site is calculating internet speed using JavaScript . When downloading larger files 250Mb+ The browser crashes. (Chrome , opera , Firefox ). It is saving all test files to DOM. I saw that the memory usage of the browser goes up like crazy while testing 100Mbps + speed connections.

My question: is there any way to limit the memory usage of browsers? Or there is any limit on using browser DOM ?
After using a file, will making it "Undefined" actually delete the item from system memory ?

I saw this browser crash issue after downloading 250Mb + data (next file 250 Mb so 512mb saved in DOM)

Comment: Why are you saving it in memory at all?

Comment: Saving it to the browser dom because we have to test upload speed . The last downloaded data will be uploaded back .

Comment: Could you not just send 250 mb of random data ? As I see it, the content of the file does not matter so much as its size; and you don't need to save anything.

Comment: We also need to test upload speed , without storing anything how to do it ? Generating random data using Javascript at client side may create the application Freez . Thanks for your comment .

Comment: Previous saved files can be deleted from memory using jsvascript ?

Comment: Variable can make "undefined" . it actually Delete  it from client RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You do not need specific data to test network speed.** What matters is the size of the data (here, 250 mb). Also, to be sure you are testing for the real speed, there is the additional requirement of not using trivial data (that is, not using all zero, or a quickly repeating pattern).

You may generate 1 mb of random data (or whatever amount that does not crash the application) and send it 250 times : the server still sees 250mb of data, and you do not need to store anything (except that 1 mb).

This works because you are **testing for speed** : you do not need to check that the data sent is the same as the received data, because the **integrity of your data is already insured** by the underlying TCP/IP protocol.

Concerning **freeing javascript memory** :  what you can do is assigning the variable another value (`var = null;`), and check that you do not hold any other reference to that variable. It is then eligible to be garbage collected : the interpreter may or may not free it, depending on its implementation -- **you have no control over that beyond this point**.